# Open Task Scheduler, Open the Create Basic Task Window and Assign an Action Via Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I know that via the command line and by using the `taskschd.msc` command we can open the Task Scheduler application. However, I would like to go a little bit further with that:

I would like to open Task Scheduler, open the *Create Basic Task* Window with an specific Action, say "Start A Program". Is there a way to pre-fill these values (task name, trigger, etc.) via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

here's the syntax.. try this

```
 Schtasks /create /sc ScheduleType /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun 
[/s Computer [/u [Domain\]User [/p Password]]] [/ru {[Domain\]User | System}] 
[/rp Password] [/mo Modifier] [/d Day[,Day...] | *] [/m Month[,Month...]] [/i IdleTime] 
[/st StartTime] [/ri Interval] [{/et EndTime | /du Duration} [/k]] [/sd StartDate]
 [/ed EndDate] [/it] [/Z] [/F]
```